# Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception interrupt after update software

Tags: 20.04, kernel

after update software by update manager of Ubuntu I got this error. I try to find solutions here but it seem to be different with my case. I need to find error information from this console then try to fix it. If not I have to reinstall OS.

My version Ubuntu: 20.04

Kernel: 5.13.0-43-generic

[Console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtyJR.jpg)

Comment: I have the same issue. Booting with the older kernel and it works again.

Comment: Booting with older kernel work for me too. But there are some driver issues occurred when I tried to install for example: nvidia driver. I installed it successfully but it didn't active. When I check status it still point install folder to some folder relate to corrupted kernel. (Which I'm not sure what I can do next). That why I have to backup my data and reinstall OS. One important lesson for me is keep /home data in another partition.

Comment: 5.13.0-37-generic works for me